# "npm install -g grunt-cli" installs grunt in ~/.nvm but nvm is uninstalled

Tags: nodejs, npm

When I run `npm install -g grunt-cli` I get output about install location:
`/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/grunt -> /home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt`
although my node installation is in different folder:

> which npm
>   /opt/node.js/node/bin/npm

Some time back, I installed node using `apt install`, which installed Node.js 8.11.4. After it, I installed `nvm`. I was not happy with it and I uninstalled both, deleted `~/.nvm` directory. Now `npm install -g grunt-cli` command **creates** `~/.nvm` directory and does not add `/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/grunt` to the path (as documentation states).
None of environment variables point to `~/.nvm` folder.
Why npm uses some leftovers and does not install in location where node is?

Comment: When running `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`  grunt is installed at correct location and grunt is added to bin folder (/opt/node.js/node/bin/grunt)

Answer (score 0):

Trick was in `~/.npmrc` file. It contained line:

> prefix=/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4

It is **leftover** of nvm installation. After commenting this line installation was done to correct location.